# Application of Banach-Steinhaus?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Following problem in an exam last week:

Let $X$ be a complex normed space and $S\subset X$ an arbitrary subset. Show that if $\{ x^*(x):x\in S  \}$ is a bounded set in $\mathbb{C}$ for each $x^* \in X^*$ then there exists a $K$ s.t. $\vert\vert x\vert\vert\leq K, \forall x\in S$.

I was not able to solve it. Is it an application of Banach-Steinhaus?

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to use the canonical injection $\delta :X\hookrightarrow X^{**},x\mapsto (x^*\mapsto x^*(x))$ which is isometric. Then the family
$\{\delta(x):x\in S\}$ is pointwise bounded thus by Banach-Steinhaus bounded in the operator norm on the bidual space and since $\delta$ is isometric it is bounded in $X$ itself.

Comment: nice, but I got a litte problem: is banach steinhaus possible, since we do not have to do with a Banach space here

Comment: Sorry. You are right . You definitely need this space to be complete to apply Banach-Steinhaus. You might consider a completion of $X$.

Comment: what do you mean by "consider a completion"? is the assertion not true in our setting?

Comment: I think it is, You prove the statement for a completion and conclude that the set is already bounded in $X$

Comment: but what is the completion of $X$?

Comment: e.g. equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences, it´s unique up to isomorphisms, a standard construction. $X$ is isometrically embedded in its completion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56005/discussion-between-peter-melech-and-tubmaster).